# Packing items from the List into a List of pairs

Tags: c#, linq, list, grouping

I have a list of `ProjectItem` class instances:  `List<ProjectItem> allProjects`.

I need to obtain a `List<ProjectItemPair>` - a list of new class instances, that have `ProjectItem projectOne` and `ProjectItem projectTwo` as a properties.

I had to foreach the initial list, and using a bool switch was adding a new `ProjectItemPair` into a resulting list on every second item in iteration. This is a primitive old school approach. I am sure with Linq I can pair the project instances up effectively. How can I do it?

Comment: This is one case where I think a loop might actually be the better solution.  Loops still have their place...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could use:

```
var pairs = allProjects.Select((value, index) = > new { value, index })
                       .GroupBy(x => x.index / 2, x => x.value)
                       .Select(pair => new ProjectItemPair(pair.ElementAt(0),
                                                     pair.ElementAtOrDefault(1)))
                       .ToList();
```

The use of `ElementAtOrDefault` means the constructor will be passed `null` if there's an odd number of elements.

Another somewhat simpler alternative:

```
var pairs = Enumerable.Range(0, allProjects.Count / 2)
                      .Select(i => new ProjectItemPair(allProjects[i * 2],
                                                       allProjects[i * 2 + 1]))
                      .ToList();
```

This will omit the final element if the input has an odd number of elements, in which case you can do:

```
if ((allProjects.Count % 2) == 1)
{
    pairs.Add(new ProjectItemPair(allProjects.Last(), null);
}
```

Comment: Yes, in my case I need to consider the case when there is an odd number of projects to group. `foreach`-based "manual" grouper solves this situation easy be adding the candidate even when the pair is not "filled up". BTW, I wasn't the one to downvote! =)

Comment: @MaximV.Pavlov: Then what do you want the final pair to look like? (It's important to specify this sort of thing in the question, btw...)

Comment: The resulting `List<ProjectItemPair>` can have last projectTwo as null.